# How do I store a git branch name in a python wheel?

Tags: python, git, pip, python-wheel

I am developing python code locally and then testing it out in a cloud environment by packaging that code up into a wheel and uploading it to that environnment.
My current naming convention for these wheels looks like

`project_name-0.[EPOCH_IN_SECONDS]+myusername-py3-none-any.whl`
e.g.
`project_name-0.1283453523+myusername-py3-none-any.whl`

So, you can see that I'm already doing things unconventionally - e.g. instead of using a proper minor version, I'm using an epoch.

pip can install this, but my issue is that I cannot easily determine which *git branch* was used to create that wheel, which makes it hard to review old test runs.

I would like to embed the branch name directly into the wheel name to make it easily visible. The issue with *that* is that people can name branches anything that git allows, and some git-allowed branch names are not allowed within parts of the wheel filename. For example

`project_name-0.3582352+myusername_this--branchname---has-consecutive-hyphens-py3-none-any.whl`

would raise a
`ERROR: project_name-0.3582352+myusername_this--branchname---has-consecutive-hyphens-py3-none-any.whl is not a valid wheel filename.` (and would not tell the user *why* the wheel name is inappropriate because I assume it's merely performing a regex match)

So - how can I associate a python wheel with the git branch that created it? Is there some metadata within the wheel that I could leverage?

Comment: Git branches don't means much. A year later you cannot return to the same point in history — the branch moved forward, or was reset, or was completely removed. Do not store branch name — store abbreviated or full commit ID.

Comment: I fully agree with @phd to use the commit ID instead of the branch name. It also solves your syntax problem as well. Maybe use `git rev-parse --short @` if you don't want the full 40 chars.

Comment: From my point of view, what you need is to find a way to add the branch name in the version string (not the wheel name per se). So if I were you I would study the [_PEP 440_](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/) which is the standard for version strings, maybe there is a solution for your use case in there somewhere.